# PYTHON | Replace json response with custom text

Tags: python, json, post, request

so I have a simple python script to print a status code of a website post request...

This is the output I am getting:

```
{"success": false, "error": "Incomplete request"}
```

But I want it to print this instead:

```
Error! Incomplete Request
```

Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: Isnt it pretty straightforward? And yes its possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python3:

```py
if not response['success']:
    print(f"Error! {response['error']}")
```

python2:

```py
if not response['success']:
    print("Error! {0}".format(response['error']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
# suppose response={"success": false, "error": "Incomplete request"}
# I suppose false is False since the dict should have been decoded from json to Python
if (not response['success'] and response['error'] == 'Incomplete request'):
    print('Error! Incomplete request')
```

Comment: @WooxHimself, if it worked you can accept the answer. Anyway you should read the question guidelines of StackOverflow before asking a new straightforward question.